# Doubts and questions about ghusl

Tags: ghusl, self-purification

Asalam alaykum brothers and sisters

I recently did ghusl but I am having doubts of whether I reached every part of my body with water. I am almost certain that water reached every part of my body but I am unsure whether I scrubbed every part perfectly.

Also, since the hands can not reach all parts of the back, what should one do in this situation? I tried my best to get water back there and am pretty sure I covered  it but I am still asking.

Jazak Allah

Answer (score 0):

Wiswas are from shaitaan. I know a lot of people,
say that but it is the truth. The same happens to me. I feel impure most of the time after ghusl but if you have let eater pass through your whole body and made sure there is no dirt on there, then you have completed your ghusl.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me too, but I read that it’s more about if the water as reached your whole body yes you should scrub however the water touching the whole body is the most important part